# Flask-admin: differentiate accessability between views

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I would like to differentiate accessability to the views (index, create, edit) in flask-admin. It can be done at the level of all views concerning particular model by overriding the method: is_accessible.

```
def is_accessible(self):
    return current_user.is_authenticated # using flask-login
```

I need that some users will be able to browse data, but without permission to create new records. On the othe rhand other users should be able to create
and edit records. Any help will be appreciated.

**Solution**

I have overriden _handle_view method which is called before every view.

```
def _handle_view(self, name, **kwargs):
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return self.unauthorized_access()

    permissions = self.get_permissions(name)
    if not current_user.can(permissions):
        return self.forbidden_access()

    return None #access granted
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't terribly well documented, but I think you can override the `is_action_allowed` method on a ModelView class to get the behavior you want. The API documentation doesn't say much about this, but I found a better example from the [changenotes](http://mrjoes.github.io/2012/08/27/flask-admin-102.html) when it was introduced:

> You can control which actions are available for current request by
>   overriding is_action_allowed method:
>
> ```
> from flask.ext.admin.actions import action
>
> class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
>     def is_action_allowed(self, name):
>         if name == 'merge' and not user.superadmin:
>             return False
>
>         if name == 'delete' and not user.admin:
>             return False
>
>         return super(MyModelAdmin, self).is_action_allowed(name)
> ```

I haven't tried this myself, so I can't attest to whether the example actually works without other changes.

Answer (score 0):

`Flask-User` seems like what you want. You specify a `UserRoles` class, a `Roles` class, and a `User` class which you already have. You assign a `UserRole` to a `User` and then in your `is_accessible` method can differentiate what you want to do (read/write/edit) based on your role.

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-User/

```
# Define User model
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True, unique=True)
    ...
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='user_roles',
            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

# Define Role model
class Role(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)

# Define UserRoles model
class UserRoles(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```